# Question on how to write an element in a generating group of the form $\langle a, b \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Let's say $G$ is a group, and $G = \langle a, b\rangle$, so that $\{a,b\}$ is the generating set of $G$, where $a,b \in G$.

There are various ways to describe the group $\langle a,b\rangle$, but we can say that it contains all members of $G$ that can be written as the finite product of elements in this set and their inverse.

My question is, if $g \in G$, then I know $g$ can be written in terms of $a, \, b$, and their inverses, but is there a closed form for this?

For example, can we say that $g = a^m b^n a^{-p} b^{-q}$ for some integers $m,n,p,q$? My gut says no, because if $G$ is not abelian, then, whose to say that $g$ doesn't equal $b^n a^m b^{-q} a^n$?

So, is it even possible to write a closed form for $g$ in general? Or is it only in special cases, like for abelian groups?

Thanks!

**Edit**----In light of the comments, suppose that $G$ is not the free group. Is it then possible to write the elements in $G$ in closed form, or is the answer still "it depends"?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is $G$ the free group on those letters?  Are there relations between $a,b$?

Comment: You seem to be quite close to describing a free group. You should do some investigation into that.

Comment: If you are speaking of the free group, then all sorts of words are allowed.  $ab^2ab^{-4}a^{17}$ for one.

Comment: I didn't realize defining $G$ in this was ambiguous, which is interesting! 
So, what if we suppose $G$ is not the free group. Would we then be able to write the elements of $G$ in a closed form? I'll edit my question to reflect the comments.

Comment: No. In general, there is no algorithm to decide if a word in the generators of a group is the trivial element, so there is no way to, *in general*, say anything about anything like this.